# Selecting only sequence group by

Tags: python, algorithm, pandas, dataframe

My data set has been sorted and filtered based on below in a pandas dataframe;

```
name id     id2 year    sales   seq
a    00632  00  2006    200.00  0
a    00632  00  2007    380.00  1
a    00632  00  2010    73.00   2
a    00632  00  2011    147.00  3
a    00632  00  2012    80.00   4

b    00003  00  2009    153.00  0
b    00003  00  2010    390.00  1
b    00003  00  2011    730.00  2
b    00003  00  2012    312.00  3
b    00003  00  2013    179.00  4
```

I am facing trouble figuring out how to segregate the non sequential years. I only one the data set to be returned as;

```
a    00632  00  2010    73.00   2
a    00632  00  2011    147.00  3
a    00632  00  2012    80.00   4

b    00003  00  2009    153.00  0
b    00003  00  2010    390.00  1
b    00003  00  2011    730.00  2
b    00003  00  2012    312.00  3
b    00003  00  2013    179.00  4
```

The logic is basically to remove the records by name, where year is less sequential than 3 years.

So for records like below will be removed as they are only sequential for 2 years.

```
name id     id2 year    sales   seq
a    00632  00  2006    200.00  0
a    00632  00  2007    380.00  1
```

I hope it makes sense, as I am having trouble trying to figure out the algorithm of such logic.

Answer (score 1):

A way in two steps.

I assume that `df` is sort by `'id','year'`.

First, find the lines where year + 2 is present on line + 2 , for each `'id'` :

```
In [15]: firstyears=(df.groupby('id')['year'].shift(-2)-df['year'])==2
# [ False False  True False False | True  True  True False False ]
```

And select the good lines using the logical or (|) operator. `firstyears.shift(1)` will select the next years, and `firstyears.shift(2)` the *next next*.

```
In [16]: df.loc[ firstyears | firstyears.shift(1) | firstyears.shift(2) ]
Out[16]: 
  name   id  id2  year  sales  seq
2    a  632    0  2010     73    2
3    a  632    0  2011    147    3
4    a  632    0  2012     80    4
5    b    3    0  2009    153    0
6    b    3    0  2010    390    1
7    b    3    0  2011    730    2
8    b    3    0  2012    312    3
9    b    3    0  2013    179    4
```

Comment: Hey there. Seems to be working. I am having trouble understanding the below code:
`df.loc[ firstyears | firstyears.shift(1) | firstyears.shift(2) ]` 
Do you think you can help me undesrstand?